# How to print a number into specific length of space in Java?

Tags: java, string, formatting, fractions

I want to print a fractional number into specific length of space with formatting, in Java. But the length will defined while algorithm running, so I can't use straight formatting, such as:

`System.out.printf("%8.1f", number)`

For example that lenght "8" will defined somewhere else while code running, how can I configure it to make it automatic depends on code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, where your formatting is determined by some 'length' defined in the code:

```
double x = 5.2375484914759291;
int length = 8;
String format = "%."+length+"f";
System.out.printf(format,x);
//5.23754849 is the output for printf("%.8f",5.2375484914759291)
```

By concatenating formatting strings to your number variable, you can specify the formatting. Here is an example of formatting the width for an int:

```
int y = 247;
int width = 8;
String formatWidth ="%0" + width + "d";
System.out.printf(formatWidth,y);
//00000247 is the output for printf("%08d",247)
```

Extending this to format both length and width:

```
double z = 247.7526;
int length = 2;
int width = 8;
String formatBoth = "%0" + width + "." + length + "f";
System.out.printf(formatBoth,z);
//00247.75 is the output for printf("%08.2f",247.7526)
```

You could also play around with your formatting string by declaring length and width as String variables, depending on your code.

Answer (score 1):

Simply build the string with concatenation

```
int x = 8;
System.out.printf("%" + x + ".1f\n", 1.123);
```